# Creating Custom Components in iOS

Tags: ios, custom-controls

Alright - I'm new to iOS and trying to do some simple things. Please correct my terminology if I'm not using it correctly.

**Problem**:

I want to create a "custom component" - just a simple compound component of an UIImageView (*image), UILabel (*title) and UITextView (*description).

In Android, this involves:

1. Creating a new class
2. Creating an xml file to use as the layout
3. Creating an instance of this class in your activity (dynamic) or in the xml (static).

**Steps I've taken in iOS**:

1. Created a new .xib document - "MyImage" --> `Extending UIView`
2. Created a new class - "MyImage.m" and "MyImage.h"
3. Added the `@property` blocks to the `MyImage.h` file.
4. In the `.xib`, I changed the Custom Class to `MyImage`, dragged a UILabel, UIImageView and UITextView into the storyboard and hooked up the appropriate Referencing Outlets to the `@properties` defined in step 3.
5. In `ViewController.m`, I added:

   @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet MyImage *myImage;
6. In `Main.storyboard`, I changed the Custom Class of the UIView to MyImage and added its Reference Outlet to myImage.

So, I think that should have hooked everything up. When I launch the app, the simulator shows an empty screen - none of the dummy text I made for the label/description show up.

Next, I tried to change/add text in the `ViewController.m` `-ViewDidLoad` method, with:

```
self.myImage.title.text = @"This is the Title";
self.myImage.description.text = @"This is the descriptive description. Look how describing it is of the content that is being described.";
```

It still won't show up. Thank you for any help!